# Get channel message list and send message on a private channel

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I'm trying to get message list and send a message on a private channel. I'm using `@slack/client`.
I've previously tried using slack-node library which was able to send a message to the private channel but I was unable to list old messages there:

```
var Slack = require('slack-node');
slack = new Slack('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

slack.api('chat.postMessage', {
    text: reportString,
    channel: '#my-channel'
}, function (err, response) {
});
```

It was working, but using this other library which is more maintained and it claims to be low-level I can't see private channels:

```
var RtmClient = require('@slack/client').RtmClient;
var MemoryDataStore = require('@slack/client').MemoryDataStore;

var token = "xoxp-2440864763-18324328800-65435386595-a46d0b859c";

var slack = new RtmClient(token, { logLevel: 'debug', dataStore: new MemoryDataStore() });
slack.start();
```

`slack.channels` doesn't contain only public channels and using `slack.channels.getChannelByName` doesn't get the private channel I want.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty confusing, but what you may be looking for when looking for a private channel is what is actually called a [group](https://github.com/slackhq/node-slack-sdk/blob/master/lib/clients/web/facets/groups.js) in the node-slack-sdk.

P.S. if that is your real token i suggest revoking and redacting it since it's now out in the wild.